# How to filter rows with select values from one column but with common ids?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame `df` with the following columns:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
value <- c("A","B","C","C","C","C","C","B","C")
```

I want to filter rows which have either value `A` or `B` and `C` for a common ID.

Expected outcome of filter:

```
ID    Value
1     A
1     B
1     C
3     B
3     C
```

How can I do this?

This did not work

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter((Value == "A" | Value == "B") & Value == "C")
```

Comment: Not very clear about the desired outcome. Can you post an example of what you want to obtain from the code?

Comment: How can value equal “C” while also being equal to either “A” or “B”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `any()` to return `TRUE` if any of the elements in a group is `TRUE`. So working example:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
value <- c("A","B","C","C","C","C","C","B","C")
df <- data.frame(ID,value)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(any(value %in% c("A","B")) & any(value == "C"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID  value
  <dbl> <fctr>
1     1      A
2     1      B
3     1      C
4     3      B
5     3      C
```

Hope this helps!